# How to reset QGIS installed on Windows to 'first run' state?

Tags: qgis, windows

The title sums it up, I'm trying to reset QGIS to its first run state under Windows 7 and XP. Deleting the *.qgis* folder in my user directory goes a long way to achieving this, but certain things persist such as:

- The load state of core plugins
- Recent Projects list
- Options

And presumably others besides this list

Where are these bits of information stored?

Using QGIS 1.7.4 (411aff6)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most of that information is stored in the good ol' windows registry.

Check under:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\QuantumGIS
```

I think you can just nuke that whole entry and QGIS will just recreate it when it runs again.